# How do I get the number of bugs reported per month on Jira?

Tags: jira, jql

I am new to Jira and am trying to find the number of bugs reported on Jira per month using JQL query.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you could use the **basic mode** in **Issues tab**, to arrive at the report

Basic mode generates the JQL in the background with help of dropdowns and selections, Advanced lets you use the JQL

**Requested JQL Query Below,** for Month November

```
project = *YourprojectName* AND issuetype in (Bug, "Story bug") AND created >= 2018-11-01 AND created <= 2018-11-30
```